# Bigamy/Deception UK Spouse Visa

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, visa-bans, deception

I recently discovered that my husband had entered into a marriage of convenience with a British citizen while still married to me. We are still living together as husband and wife. He used a divorce decree from a previous marriage to show that he was free to marry. They have submitted an application for a spouse visa and he has done the biometrics and I believe he has submitted his passport (it is not among our other legal documents). I have informed the Home Office of our existing marriage by submitting supporting documents. We are currently living in Canada.

Will he be subject to a 10 year ban? Will the Home Office follow up on the information I have provided (I did speak to an Intelligence Officer from the Home Office, who confirmed receipt of the information)? I understand that marriage is not required to apply for a spouse visa (a common law union of the sorts could also suffice), so could he still be approved?

Can I apply for a visitor's visa to visit a friend or will I be impacted by his pending application? My friend has sent an invitation letter for both of us. Should I have her just send a letter for me? I have no intention to settle there. I am a Therapist here in Canada and I am very connected to my community. We are both citizens of Barbados and permanent residents in Canada.

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

The application was denied because the income thresholds were not met. He has submitted another spouse visa application, this time with the finances as desired. Is it possible that the Home Office had not looked at the evidence I had submitted initially? If this is a second fraudulent application, is he likely to be banned if it is discovered? I have started divorce proceedings which he is contesting.

Comment: _Can I apply for a visitor's visa to see a friend or will I be impacted by his pending application_? No, you’re not going to be made to carry his cross.

Comment: When asked in Jan this question was about your husband, and today has been changed to wife and all gender pronouns have swapped, any reason why?

Comment: This is quite odd. Citizens of Barbados don't need a visa to visit the UK either.

Comment: Perhaps ‘check applicant meets basic eligibility criteria’ is done before ‘verify validity of supporting documents’, since it is much easier and quicker to do and would lead to a rapid refusal. Why waste time verifying documents/carrying out more complex checks when the answer is ‘no’ from the outset

Answer (score 10):

> Can I apply for a visitor's visa to see a friend or will I be impacted
> by his pending application?

Everyone **in theory** is approved or denied on their own merits. Even if a person is affected by a related persons crime, in your case chances of an adverse effect are remote considering you’re the one who reported the crime.

> My friend sent an invitation letter for he and I. Should I have her
> just send letter for me?

That of course would be preferable. Extricating yourself from an association with such a blatant law breaker would be viewed positively by all parties including UK immigration.

> Will he be subject to a 10 year ban? Will the Home Office follow up on
> my information?

He will if it’s investigated and conclusive evidence is established. Under the current immigration climate, that is very likely.Tolerance for illegal immigration is at perhaps an all time low.

[1.2 RFL5.2 How long are applicants automatically refused for?](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/immigration-offender-rfl05-paragraph-3207b-and-a320/immigration-offender-rfl05-paragraph-3207b-and-a320#header8)

- > 10 years if they practised deception (which includes using false documentation) in support of a previous visa application.

Comment: The original question has been heavily edited by the poster (for reasons best known to them) to the point the answer doesn’t seem to make sense.